# Entity Framework - Fill remaining properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that receives a Dto Model and map to a Domain Model:

Method:

```
public void CreateAd(CreateAdDto adDto) { 

    var adDomain = Mapper.Map<CreateAdDto, Ad>(adDto);
}
```

Dto Object:

```
public class CreateAdDto
{
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }
}
```

The Dto map the Domain Model:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

And the Model:

```
public class Model
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameStandard { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get in the CreateAd method access to the Model.NameStandard value, but when I do the mapping, I only have the Model Id, so how do I get the Model Entity with all the properties including the NameStandard value?

Do I have to make a Call to the **Model GetById(Model_Id)** to get the Model properties or there is another way like a property in the Attach that can bring all the properties?

Or Should I use the Model in the ViewModel and pass to the Dto and to the Domain with all the properties?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to call `GetById` (probably `Find` or `SingleOrDefault`?) or use explicit loading:

```
context.Ads.Attach(adDomain);
context.Entry(adDomain).Reference(a => a.Model).Load();
```

(EF >= 4.1/`DbContext` syntax)

Or pass `Model` to the view in hidden fields and retrieve them back from the view. This might only be a performance question (I could not tell what is better in performance) or maybe a security question (does `NameStandard` only contain data the user is allowed to see when he inspects the html markup or the traffic on the wire?).

**Edit**

Sorry, the explicit loading above is nonsense. It would only make sense if you have `Ad.Id` available and want to fetch the related `Model` (if the `Ad` already exists in the database).

So, only `GetById` is useful in this case.

Comment: Hi, that's what I suspected but I was hoping that this was not necessary, so I created a Method to "Load" the rest of the data do the Entity. Thank you for your help ;)